# Cast SshClient to SftpClient

Tags: c#, ssh

I am using [Renci.SshNet](https://github.com/alexbikfalvi/Renci.SshNet/blob/master/SshClient.cs) to send files and execute commands securely on my ubuntu server.

Anyways I often need to send files and also execute commands. So what I am doing now is this:

```
using (Renci.SshNet.SshClient client1 = new Renci.SshNet.SshClient("someDomain.com", 22, "root", new PrivateKeyFile(@"C:\Path\To\PrivateKey\id_rsa")))
{
    // connect
    client1.Connect();

    // execute a command
    var c = client1.RunCommand("echo 'hello world' > /root/test.txt");

    // create a second connection in order to download a file 
    SftpClient client_2 = new SftpClient(client1.ConnectionInfo);
    client_2.Connect();

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("output.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
             client_2.DownloadFile("/root/test.txt", fs);
}
```

**My question is can I cast from SshClient to SftpClient so that I do not have to create 2 connections?** It will be great if I could do something like this:

```
 SftpClient client_2 = (SftpClient)client1;
```

Or another solution is to pass the files in base64 format. If I do something like this to download a file will it be considered as bad practice?

```
 var fileConentInBase64 = client1.RunCommand("cat'/root/someFile' | base64");
```

Using the same terminology to upload a file I will do:

```
 client1.RunCommand($"echo {base64ContentOfFile} | base64 -d > /path/to/file")
```

Comment: While they both derive from `BaseClient`, they are not derived from each other so it would seem that casting would result in a compiler error (I assume you figured that out when you tried to type in the above code).

Comment: I'd like to be able to asynchrously delete a file. This isn't natively supported by Renci.SshNet. If I were able to construct a SshCommand-object in a SFtp-connection, I could implement it myself. I could, of course, do _everything_ through an SshClient, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know about cast in C# when you do it with objects the classes must have a inheritage in common. 
[The C# documentation will be clearer than me](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

*So if SftpClient inherit from BaseClient you may be able to do it in some way or another.* **As sayed in the comments of your posts it's actually impossible to do it for that exact reason**
Sorry I red the doc a bit fast.

Maybe I'm missing something but couldn't you do everything with SSH ? [From what I'm reading here it is possible to "upload" and "download" a file with SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh#106482)

Comment: How do I upload a file with  Renci.SshNet.SshClient  which is a ssh client? Maybe that is the solution but I do not think it is possible since that runs on c# and windows.

Comment: For that reason it exists a `ScpClient` but then I will end up with the same problem. https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/wiki/ScpClient:-Remote-path-transformation

Comment: I've never used Renci.SshNet so I don't know. I was just trying to give you a direction to look into. It is very probable that I'm far more clueless than you. But from what I understand you may be just stuck in that situation for no good reasons. Is there a real problem about having 2 connections being made ? It is not optimal but does it affect greatly your project ? if it doesn't I would continue working on other more important things until some experienced developper (which I'm not) give you a good response on here.

Comment: I guess  you are right I will just create 2 connections and move on.